# Run "dynamic" arguments with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

Is there an easier way to specify arguments for a program in Eclipse? I know you can go to Run > Run Configurations... > Argument tab, but with the program I'm working on I need to be able to test different files and file formats, so having to do this every time I want to test a different argument would waste a lot of time.

I could set up different Run configurations for different arguments, but that's still a but of a kludge. I'd still have to edit the different configurations if I wanted to use a new file.

The Debug view has an interactive console, but it doesn't appear you can use it to pass arguments to the program, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already consider a unit testing framework to solve this? Having a 'main' class, that encapsulates all the program options and input parameters well from the 'plain' `main()` function, would help much here (and is approved and robust design anyway).

Latest Eclipse CDT (Kepler, may be even Juno) supports C++ unit testing with various frameworks (cppunit, googletest) BTW.

Comment: A unit testing framework seems maybe a bit too complex for what I want to do. I am working on expanding a Piet interpreter and need to test different Piet programs of varying image format. Npiet, which I am using as the base, currently supports PPM, PNG, and GIF, but I would like to add more formats and expand the language.

Comment: @SeanHeiss There's usually nothing _complex_ integrating with a unit testing framework, unless you didn't provide proper units being testable (as mentioned it's a matter of appropriate design). The main purpose of a unit testing framework is exactly to simplify this. Think it over, seriously! Show some code: How you're going to extend 'Npiet's basic implementation?
May be I can show you a way how to unit test it in a way you'd like to achieve (You might be able to select from particular test runs instead of need for defining gazillions of run configurations).

Comment: What I mean by "complex" is that I've not done such a thing before, so I don't know if the trade-off for learning how to do it and implementing it is worth it. All I need to do for testing is write "npiet X.Y" (where X = file name, Y = file format) in the console, so I'm not sure if implementing an entire framework is worth the time!

Comment: @SeanHeiss What's the essence of that 'Npiet' extension you've done? A plugin model or what? You don't need to implement a 'framework', you're just going to use it to run your test cases with all conditions (file formats, concrete file samples) you need.
Just check this: [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer)

Comment: Actually, it is open source so I am just adding onto the code, no extensions or plugins. A unit test might actually be helpful. I will need to test different file formats containing different instructions in the source code, so this could be helpful. Thanks! :)

Comment: @SeanHeiss Glad I could help! I'd expect an OSS project to come with unit tests anyway. For me it's an indicator of quality and I seriously consider this, when integrating s.th. with my production code!